# Is the Laws of Form consistent in relation to PA?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

G. Spencer-Brown wrote in his book Laws of Form from 1969, that (as you can see in Chapters 9 and 10) his LoF is complete and independent. In fact this proves, that LoF can't deduce paradoxes of the form $ p \wedge \neg p $. So my question is the following:

As we know by Gödels Incompleteness Theorems, every System, which contains Peano Arithmetic is incomplete. Now Spencer-Brown deduced in the Appendix 4 & 5 of my german edition the PA with his LoF. What does that mean? Is PA now complete in the interpretation of LoF or is LoF in fact incomplete instead of complete?

Am I missing here something? Also I did not find any information on this subject. I hope some of you can explain this.

Comment: No detailed knowledge of the book [Laws of Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_Form), but IMO the claim "that certain well-known mathematical conjectures of very long standing, such as the four color theorem, Fermat's Last Theorem, and the Goldbach conjecture, are provable using extensions of the [so-called] primary algebra" are quite suspect.

Comment: Maybe you have to take into account the fact that "Peano axioms" may reefer to the [first-order version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic), to which Godel's Th applies, but also to the [second-order one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_arithmetic).

Comment: First of all a correction : Every CONSISTENT strong enough theory (strong enough to satisfy the representation theorem - containing PA is sufficient) is incomplete. That Goldbach conjecture is provable ( should that have been claimed ) is a hypothetical statement. Noone knows whether this conjecture (should it be true) is provable in PA or ZFC or in an extension of ZFC. It is strongly BELIEVED to be provable in ZFC however.

Comment: Details are needed... According to [Wiki's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_Form#The_primary_algebra_(Chapter_6)) so-called primary-algebra seems to be equivalent to boolean algebra and thus to sentential logic, which is complete and consistent. This is, IMO, the gist of the statement "that LoF can't deduce paradoxes of the form $p∧¬p$".

Comment: According to the same source "Chapter 11 of LoF introduces equations of the second degree, composed of recursive formulae ... that can be interpreted via Alonzo Church's Restricted Recursive Arithmetic (RRA)." This is not [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic).

Comment: Obviously Spencer-Brown wrote some strange papers... so in fact his LoF interpreted for the arithmetic is nothing really special and is not corresponding to Gödels Theorems?

Comment: I've browsed the Book and IMO there is nothing "special" regarding arithmetic. The "logic system" is complete in the same sense of propositional (and maybe predicate) logic. For arithmetic, new postulates are added, exactly as in the case of Peano arithmetic. The "completeness" of the logic is not the same of the "incompleteness" of the arithmetic (see relevant literature: standard math log textbooks).